# Dynamic Views on Android Activity

Tags: android, sqlite

I am quite new to Android development. I managed to get data saved to SQLite database. Now, what I want is to view these data when I call viewData(). I have viewData() which shows data as a Toast as I made it as a sample. Now I need these data to show on a new activity but the number of data to show is depending on how many data is in the database at the moment, If user saved 10 items then I want all the 10 items to shown up. How can I do it?

What is the best way to show data from SQLite database on an activity. Since I don't know to use ListView, I used TableLayout on the other activity where user feed data.

I hope my question is clear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The best way is to use a recyclerview. You should look into it.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it if I am using TablelLayout?

Comment: That would be the wrong way to do it, and it would be way easier to user a RecyclerView - plus the sooner you learn about lists and adapters the better.